# Drive.Files.remove(fileId) remove the item but return an error message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am struggling with code that does everything I want, but returns an error message at the end of the function, which prevents the rest of the script from running.

I am using this script:

```
function abc(){

    var fileName = "file name";
    var tabName = "tab";
    clear(tabName,"A:AE");
    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = "folder id";  
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();

    var resource = {
        title: excelFile.getName(),
        mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
        parents: [{id: folderId}],
    };

    var id = Drive.Files.insert(resource,blob).id;
    var newsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getRange("A:AE").getValues();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(tabName).getRange("A:AE").setValues(newsheet);
    Logger.log("ok so far");
    Drive.Files.remove(id);
}
```

I want to delete the file I just created, which it does perfectly, but it generates an error message  as follows:

> Document 1b0pLioLpwZndFuW4kRQzxd5gkfZjWFIT5Qr8HV-LJvo is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

It creates the file, copies the values to another spreadsheet, and deletes the file created, just as it has to be. And then the script ends, and I need to run other functions as well.

Any idea how to fix it?

I also tried `DriveApp.removeFile(file),` but the script finishes and does not delete the file from the folder.

This is the error message:

> "Document 1TVRiqJKN_bSXLW8B02XzUlTOUgT192prUYYwvBwu89w is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)"

and this is the logs the script generated:

```
[19-11-19 08:58:22:466 PST] TSC cleaned
[19-11-19 08:58:22:466 PST] TSC has started
[19-11-19 08:58:26:737 PST] TSC file generated on ID = 1TVRiqJKN_bSXLW8B02XzUlTOUgT192prUYYwvBwu89w
[19-11-19 08:58:27:363 PST] 1TVRiqJKN_bSXLW8B02XzUlTOUgT192prUYYwvBwu89w
[19-11-19 08:58:27:497 PST] TSC copied to destination sheet and id = 1TVRiqJKN_bSXLW8B02XzUlTOUgT192prUYYwvBwu89w
[19-11-19 08:58:28:171 PST] TSC file deleted
[19-11-19 08:58:30:323 PST] TSC imported
```

The last line "TSC Imported" is the last line of the function, so it looks like it is completing the function but in the end the message comes. I might have to try other options instead of the Drive API. Thank you for your help guys, I'll let you know if I succeed.

Comment: Where in your code are you even defining what Drive is? This looks totally messed up. Please make the simplest example of exactly what you are trying to do without all the extra stuff.

Comment: I enabled the Drive API. I want to import an excel file into a sheet I already have, the easiest way I found is to create a GSheets file from the excel file, then import the values of this file to the sheet I have. So I create a GSheet from excel file, copy the data to my sheet and then delete the file created. All is working fine but ate the end it generates that error, I moved that function to the last in the order, so it runs the script completely fine, but still generates the error at the end.

Comment: Try pausing the code before the deletion: `Utilities.sleep(5000);Drive.Files.remove(id);`

Comment: @Alexandre why don't you just remove the file with DriveApp I don't understand why you need to use the Drive API?

Comment: I am using the Drive API to create the file, and when I use DriveApp to remove the file, the script finishes but does not delete the file from the folder.

Comment: For what it's worth.  I am having the same issue.  code executes just once. file does get deleted but error shows as file is missing. I've tried enveloping the ".remove" method in a try/catch and it doesn't trigger the catch. Instead it continues  the script as it should i.e the file deletes but it generates a script error. I've tried utilities sleep, no joy.  I've tried "gettingById" immediately before the remove -  The file is retrieved but still the same error message is logged. weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing same problem. If I only run `Drive.Files.insert` and next `Drive.Files.remove` file is removed and no error message, but if I open file with `SpreadsheetApp.openById` before `Drive.Files.remove` then file is removed and script continue but I get that error. I was trying `Utilities.sleep` with up to (barely sane) 20 seconds before remove and run script few times with random results(sometimes error sometimes without error).
How to fix that?

Comment: Hello jack, as I mentioned, I didn’t go through this error anymore, I just created a new folder where I leave all the created sheets there. In my case I don’t really need to remove them, but maybe you can create a script that deletes all the files from that folder once a day or whatever suits your necessity. I didn’t go through this option as well but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue too and couldn't pin down exactly what was causing it but found that if you split up the file creation and deletion into separate functions and run them individually, you don't get this error.  But, if you call both functions from within a third function, the error is thrown.

Runs fine when initiated manually...

```
createFile() {
  let fileId = Drive.Files.insert(fileId, blob);
}
```

Also runs without error when initiated manually...

```
deleteFile() {
  Drive.Files.remove(fileId);
}
```

Fails with error saying the file cannot be found...

```
createAndDelete() {
  createFile();
  deleteFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `@Alan Wells` mentioned in the comments, you are not giving Drive enough time to generate the file, copy the values and delete it.

Try adding `Utilities.sleep(15000);` after the `Drive.insert`.

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds).

Comment: the script is actually deleting the file as it should do, but still returns the error message.

Comment: @Alexandre maybe you are running the function twice, can you create a counter to check how many times your code is executing?

Comment: I posted the logs in the main post, I don't know what else to do, I think I'll try other options and see how it goes. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys I ended up creating an archive for the files so I won't delete them, I'll just leave them in this folder I created as an archive.
Thank you for you help.