# Error with functioning Script - "Document <Doc ID. is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?) "

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

I am running a script to pull a weekly schedule excel file attached to an email and posting it to a google sheet. Currently I'm triggering it manually. The code appears to be working correctly and goes to completion based on logger statements but it gives this error code each time.

`Document <Sheet ID> is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or maybe you don't have read access?)`

The referenced sheet ID is not the sheet i'm working on so i presume it's the temporary document that's been created and deleted. I'm not sure how to get rid of this error. Again, the code appears to be working as intended despite the error.

```
    function getExcelFile()
{
  var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Guelph/Weekly Schedules").getThreads(0,1);
  //var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(‘Reconciliation’).getThreads(0,1);
  
  var messages = thread[0].getMessages();
  var len = messages.length;
  var message = messages[len-1] //get last message
  var attachments = message.getAttachments(); // Get attachment of first message
  
  var xlsxBlob = attachments[0]; // Is supposes that attachments[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
  var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // There is the data in 1st tab.
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1e_pepsold-SHbnDXcQ0pvdN9AGiZ31O5XcLFU8YfcwE").getSheetByName("Current");
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id").getSheetByName(‘Data’);
  
  sheet.clearContents();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
  range.setValues(data);
  
  Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.
  
  Logger.log(new Date().getTime() - start); // Outputs time taken to run function
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a recurring problem; there is already a thread here: [Drive.Files.remove(fileId) remove the item but return an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922329/drive-files-removefileid-remove-the-item-but-return-an-error-message)

My best guess is when the script removes the file, it still uses that same file, so the script returns an error message that the recently removed file is missing.

I know this may not be the best workaround, but you can move the file to Trash instead of deleting immediately:

```
Drive.Files.trash(convertedSpreadsheetId);
```

Then you can empty the Trash manually or do it in GAS using:

```
Drive.Files.emptyTrash();
```

References:

[Trash](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/trash)

[Empty Trash](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/emptyTrash)